# Replace all chars after - in string to uppercase in JS

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have function

```
firstLetterUppercase(str: string) {
    let splitStr = str.toLowerCase().split(' ');
    for (let i = 0; i < splitStr.length; i++) {
      splitStr[i] = splitStr[i].charAt(0).toUpperCase() + splitStr[i].substring(1);
    }
    return splitStr.join(' ');
  }
```

It's work fine for string: Warszawa, Krakow, Bielsko - Biala etc.

I need change it to string 'Bielsko-biala'.
(i need first char after '-' uppercase too).

How can i make it?

Please help me

Comment: Does [this approach](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.0.4#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABMGAnAzlAMgUylHVAVQAcTCIBDdHACk1QC5EGYwBzASkQG8BYAFCJhiADZ4WJUTCgBlKKkQBeFgoB0UOFjgB3QgGFqdTmvRSZtAOSJLnANyCRyOItrioiGMsQAGO58QAHklpOXVxDigAC38YAGo47n4hJxEzUPlUAG0YAF1vdJlMnNzHVPLTcygrAFpbMvKnNQBbShJaem4lAD4WNQgoylQAQWqfE01SclRDGlpuOL70EAAjVg5aAEZOTgbG4TUAKzg2WtsHFOEAXz3UPBBUJEKw1COTsCsbe0EbgUFBCAIdBwcRqURwdi0FAYbB4AjEMgUIxWAiYGpUGi2ThAA) work for you? If yes, I'll write an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a regular expression and the replace() method to find and replace the lowercase letters after a dash with their uppercase counterparts.

```
function firstLetterUppercase(str: string) {
  let splitStr = str.toLowerCase().split(" ");
  for (let i = 0; i < splitStr.length; i++) {
    splitStr[i] =
      splitStr[i].charAt(0).toUpperCase() + splitStr[i].substring(1);
    splitStr[i] = splitStr[i].replace(/-([a-z])/g, (match) =>
      match.toUpperCase()
    );
  }
  return splitStr.join(" ");
}
```

Comment: "Try this" isn't really useful. You should add some notes to your answer to _explain_ what you've changed. Maybe add the code as a snippet too as a working example.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the updated code that will work for 'Bielsko-biala'.
In the modified function, I have added a conditional statement to check if the current word contains a hyphen ('-'). If it does, I locate the index of the hyphen using indexOf('-'). Then, it capitalizes the letter immediately after the hyphen by concatenating the relevant portions of the string with their capitalized counterparts.

```js
function firstLetterUppercase(str) {
  let splitStr = str.toLowerCase().split(' ');

  for (let i = 0; i < splitStr.length; i++) {
    if (splitStr[i].includes('-')) {
      let hyphenIndex = splitStr[i].indexOf('-');
      splitStr[i] =
        splitStr[i].charAt(0).toUpperCase() +
        splitStr[i].substring(1, hyphenIndex + 1) +
        splitStr[i].charAt(hyphenIndex + 1).toUpperCase() +
        splitStr[i].substring(hyphenIndex + 2);
    } else {
      splitStr[i] = splitStr[i].charAt(0).toUpperCase() + splitStr[i].substring(1);
    }
  }

  return splitStr.join(' ');
}

console.log(firstLetterUppercase('Bielsko-biala'))
```

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing it can be:

```
function firstLetterUppercase(str) {
  let splitStr = str.toLowerCase().split(' ');
  for (let i = 0; i < splitStr.length; i++) {
    splitStr[i] = splitStr[i].charAt(0).toUpperCase() + splitStr[i].substring(1);
  }

  //Added code
  let result = splitStr.join(' ');
  result = result.replace(/-([a-z])/g, function(match, group1) {
    return '-' + group1.toUpperCase();
  });

  return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to "replace" "all" the "characters" starting after "word border", with their "Upper case"
the easiest way would be using regular expressions:

```
/**
 * `replaceAll`(`g` regex flag) characters of any type (`.`)
 * after word border (`\b`) with their `toUpperCase`
 */
function firstLetterUppercase(str) {
  return str.replaceAll(/\b./g, c => c.toUpperCase())
}
```